# Raspberry Pi show Image while Boot

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

For a project with the Raspberry Pi, I need (it would look better) to show an image while boot. Or a text that says Booting up or so. I will use a display with HDMI, cause the Raspberry Display is too small. Also I will do everything with Python, so if there is a need to program anything, please in python.

Would be cool if you could help me :D

Nice sunday everyone :)

Fabian

Comment: this question is off topic.
There is an stack exchange for primarily Raspberry Pi question like this one. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a command line image viewer like fbi

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install fbithis will allow you to display images from the terminal.

fbi -a myphoto.jpg

then add it to init.d or something to boot as a service.

I've used this method and it works well, i also have used overlays that appear bottom right of the screen but a lot more work.

you can load the config.txt on the pi image as well and disable the rainbow startup.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this :)